# Undefined name in function

Tags: python, django

> Undefined name 'cleaned_data'

What am I doing wrong here?

code:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = cleaned_data['email']


        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `self.cleaned_data` instead

Answer (score 2):

The main point here is knowing where `cleaned_data` comes from.

I am guessing here that it is an instance attribute, so replacing it with `self.cleaned_data` should work.

Comment: Yes, it's provided by Django in its `Form` class, which, although the OP wasn't explicit about it, the original code was clearly in a subclass of it. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data